# laravel - upload and show image

Tags: image, laravel, upload

I try to upload bigger image but don't work. Image smaller from 100KB can upload but bigger can not upload.

I set on server php 
         upload_max_filesize = 32M
         post_max_size = 32M

but still can not upload.

Upload code:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $last_row = DB::table('ref')->latest()->first();

 $destinationPath = 'images/ref/'.$last_row->id; // upload path
  if(!File::exists($destinationPath)) {
     File::makeDirectory($destinationPath, $mode = 0777, true, true);
    }

  $insertedId =$last_row->id;
    $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->image->move(public_path($destinationPath), $input['image']);
    $input['idDor'] = $last_row->id;
     $input['title'] = $request->title;
    ImageGallery_referencesve::create($input);

  return view('ItemCRUDref.image-gallery',compact('insertedId'));

}
```

I can understand why i can not upload image bigger from 100KB when i set max_filesize = 32M. Any idea?

When I upload bigger image it use index page

```
      public function index()
    {
 $images =DB::table('ref')->get();
  return view('ItemCRUD.ref',compact('images'));
     }
```

My blade.php

```
 <form action="{{ url('ref') }}" class="form-image-upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-5">
        <strong>Prior:</strong>
       {!! Form::select('title', array('Yes' => 'Yes','No' => 'No'), 'No', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <strong>Add:</strong>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you set any validate for upload file request ?

Comment: No, I did not set.

Comment: Can you show us what error is returned?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have changed the settings in the wrong file.

make a test route in your laravel app like this:

```
Route::get('/php', function () {
    phpinfo();
});
```

and search for the exact path to the `Loaded Configuration File`

[image]

and then open that file and change these settings there:

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
```

Oh, and one more very important thing,you need to restart the apache or nginx server after you have made the changes!

Comment: i found this, and i don't have access to php.ini because i use server for my site :(

Comment: Well, exactly in that file you need to change those setiings, or else you will not be able to upload bigger files!